Formula based on the cell that has content
Is there a way to have a formula look at the below cells and run a formula based on the cell that contains data? Ideally I would like it create the breach time based on which column has a time and what the sla is for that column.
Hope that make sense
Sorry I will try and make it clearer.
Using the screenshot, the top row is the priority of the visit, in cell A6 is it possible to have a formula that looks at A2, A3 and A4 and set the breach time depending on what time is in the cell and which column. So for example if I enter 15:00 in cell A3 it sets the breach time as 12hrs later in cell A6, or if I put it in Cell A2 it sets it as 6hrs later.


You need to share some samples (as markdown table)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think this will work based on what I can understand from your question. These should be the rules you want to implement:
A2 (Urgent < 2 HRS): Adds 2 hours
A3 (Less Urgent < 6 HRS): Adds 6 hours
A4 (Routine < 12 HRS): Adds 12 hours
Add this formula in A6. The IF condition checks across A2, A3 and A4 and updates A6.

=IF(A2<>"", A2 + TIME(2, 0, 0), IF(A3<>"", A3 + TIME(6, 0, 0), IF(A4<>"", A4 + TIME(12, 0, 0), "")))

Note: Make sure A2, A3, A4, and A6 is formatted to TIME or General. Dont use Number. Plase let me know if this works.

This did exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.
